# How to hide div element after clicking on it and not to show after page reload

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide a div with text by clicking on "close" text with JS only.

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="message">
  <span>Text I want to hide after 
    <a>click</a> on it
  </span>
</div>
```

And the main point is not to show it after page reload.

I've tried a lot of suggestions here, but no one worked correctly for me.

Comment: You can keep a flag in the server to handle hide/show the particular div. Or you can store the hide and show information in the browser storage.

Comment: @Oleksandr Can you share the code that you have tried ?

Comment: @ArunRavindran I guess, he still wants it only in the frontend, He can use cookies / session storage, they are a much better option if it is only with frontend

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=click+div+hide+reload+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.